# Passing value servlet to Html page?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, servlets

Can any option is there where i can pass only one value from servlet to html page without displaying that value in URL.

I have a login page when i give wrong userid or password same login page should reload with a error message. But here i am not able to display error message after login fail.

I am able to pass error message from servlet to html by url like `http://localhost:8080/WebApp/html/login.html?password=sfdgdsfdsf` after this i can read the URL and display the error message. but the issue is here like that error message also display on URL.

Can anybody help on this.

Comment: Why you are using `html` as index page. Use `JSP`.

Comment: I have some restriction so i can't use jsp over there.Login page should html page only.

Comment: Send the form using POST http method. Read about securing web applications [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html#bncck), if you are using Java. Java !=JavaScript. Don't ever send a password as a parameter.

Comment: @Stefan my issue is about passing value servlet to HTML. issue not about security over web.

Comment: So why can't you use `jquery` with `ajax`. Without `jsp` it's an alternate solution.

Comment: @Janny, parameters are passing as part of of url. so it will displayed.

Comment: actually the ajax idea is probably the best

Comment: @Satya let me try with ajax.

Comment: you can try this,may be help to you.    ----->                                                       request.setAttribute("attrName", "attrValue");
   RequestDispatcher dispatchere=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp");
   dispatchere.forward(request, response);

Comment: @SanjayPatel i don't have JSP page. I have only HTML page.